# How do I make a collapsible menu in javascript?

Tags: javascript, menu

How do I make an expandable and collapsible menu in java script where clicking on one menu will expand the children inside that and collapse other expanded menu(s)?

Comment: There are about 3,000 ways.  Are you using a framework?

Comment: eminently googleable - have you even tried? SO tends to respond better to effort

Comment: in google i can only able to found the collapsiable menu script, which is not serving my purpose that the menu to collapse if you click another menu, so only one can be open at any one time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23671064/2261259

Answer (score 2):

Besides [one of SO's running jokes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471597/is-jquery-always-the-answer) for an answer, what you're wanting is an [accordion menu](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+accordion) (maybe not for the effects, but for the containment of the entire menu).

Here's a library-less solution: [Javascript And CSS Tutorial - Accordion Menus](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-and-css-tutorial-accordion-menus).

Or, an accordion-specific library/script: http://www.stickmanlabs.com/accordion/

Otherwise, if you're up for using a library and add-ons, there's plenty of options: [10 Javascript Accordion Scripts](http://tutorialblog.org/10-javascript-accordion-scripts/).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is with a jQuery plugin like this one:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/accordion

Answer (score 1):

in jQuery:

```
$(".toggle-control").click(function(){
    $(".target-div").hide();
    $(this).next().show();
});
```

if your html is something like this:

```
<p class="toggle-control">Click to expand</p>
<div class="target-div">some text here</div>
<p class="toggle-control">Click to expand</p>
<div class="target-div">some text here</div>
<p class="toggle-control">Click to expand</p>
<div class="target-div">some text here</div>
```