# My div will not slideDown() when clicked.

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to have a drop down menu on a small website I am putting together. For some reason, I can get the div that I want to slide down to fadeOut() and do other things similar but I cannot get it to slideDown(). I have no idea why. There is text on it that says "Menu".

The jQuery is below.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu").click(function(){
        $("#menu").moveDown(40px);
    });
});
```

The CSS is here

```
body {
    background-color:white;
}

#header {
    width:1024px;
    height:100px;
    margin-top:-25px;
    border:2px solid black;
    border-radius:20px;
    background-color:lightblue;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

#menu {
    position:relative;
    height:400px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:blue;
    border:2px solid black;
    border-radius:15px;
    margin-left:850px;
    margin-top:-345px;
    text-align:center;
}

#menuText {
    margin-top:360px;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#heading {
    font-family:Verdana;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:35px;
}

#myCanvas {
    background-color:white;
}

canvas {
    display:block;
    margin:2px;
}

#body {
    height:768px;
    width:1024px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius:20px;
    background-color:lightblue;
```

and the HTML is here.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Document2.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Document1.css">
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="menu">
    <p id="menuText">Menu</p>
</div>
<div id="header">
    <h1 id="heading">Hello There!</h1>
</div>
<div id="body">
    <p>This is a line on my website.</p>
    <p>This is another line on my website.</p>
    <p>I want to make a game like Super Mario.</p>
    <p>I alo want to make a Brick Breaker game.</p>
    <h3>Below is an unfinished American Flag.</h3>
    <p>The dimensions of the flag are exact. All the flag needs is some stars.</p>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="190" height="100" style="border:2px solid black"> </canvas>
    <canvas id="circle" width="500" height="250" style="border:2px solid black"> </canvas>
    <p id="date"> </p>
    </div>
<script src="Document1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I do have another Javascript document but it was only used to draw some pictures on canvas. I am an amateur so it would help if the answers were worded simply. Thank you so much for taking the time to read this and I will be so grateful if anybody can help a newbie like me.

Comment: I think `$("#menu").moveDown(40px)` would be `$("#menu").moveDown('40px')` in quotes

Comment: Is there a function `moveDown()` in jquery? I think you need [.slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/)

Comment: I am so sorry. I meant to use slideDown(); I was getting frustrated and meant tried other thigs that i thought would work. Im going to change that right now

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle link illustrating the problem?

Comment: Yes i can. give me a minute

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bailey8756/aPgwV/

Comment: @user3639468 why dont you just put your menu items on a separate div and make it initially hidden put it directly where you want it to slide down and toggle that div on click of your menu div.. check this update: http://jsfiddle.net/gTCbm/2/

Comment: That works great. I'm looking for something more smooth. You know how on the ipad if you swipe up from the bottom or down from the top a menu type thing pops up, that's what I am looking for. What you did was great though. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Ok. Instead of having the div slide down, is there another way to just shift it downwards?

Comment: Check jQuery .animate() http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Sweet thanks. I'm gonna try that tomorrow. I gotta go to bed now or else I won't be able to get up in the morning. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
slideDown() only works on the elements which is hidden with jQuery methods or css display:none.
```

In your problem your div is already at its height.

So you have to set another div which will contain your menu and set it display to none;
then on click of the `menu` you can slide it down.

I have set an example **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aPgwV/2/)**

**Update [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aPgwV/5/)**

Comment: I posted a link of my code on us fiddle. Could you edit the code on there to show me?

Comment: And is there any way to make a div just slide left or right? Becuase that's kinda what I'm trying to do. I want to have my menu but have the links on the menu be hidden off the edge of the page. Them when I click on the div I want it to slide down and show the links. I do not have any links on there yet.

Comment: @user3639468 Check the link in my answer

Comment: Change your code according to my answer to give you a better understanding of how it works

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu").click(function(){
        $("#menu").slideDown('40px');
    });
});
```

Comment: it can be moved with $("#menu").css("margin-top","40px"); but still you have a lot to work on your css

Comment: Ok. That $("#menu").css("margin-top","40px") did work but it moved the whole document. I cant figure out how to just make the #menu div slide down.

Comment: answer is logical and correct to my understanding maybe you have some other js error ... check console and write what is a issue

Comment: I oosted a jsfiddle link so you guys can see for yourselves.

Answer (score 0):

SlideDown won't work because it is already visible, try "slideUp" or "slideToggle"
to understand it better. slideDown will transition an "invisible" div to become "visible" whereas slideUp will transition a "visible" div to become "invsible".

Make your div a child of another div then toggle it like so:

change html:

> ```
> <div id="menuSlide">
>     <div id="menu">
>         <p id="menuText">Menu</p>
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```

change css:

```
    #menu {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        height: 400px;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: blue;

    }

            #menuSlide {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        height: 420px;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: pink;
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius: 15px;
        margin-left: 850px;
        margin-top: -345px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

change javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#menuSlide").click(function () {
            $("#menu").slideToggle('80px');
        });
    });
```

This will at least give you a better understanding of how it works...
Play around and make your changes accordingly

Comment: Obviously click the pink div to slide up and down, hopefully this teaches you how it works - slideToggle checks the #menu's state, if it is visible, slide up, if it is invisible slide down, you can create that logic yourself to by checking its state

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu").click(function(){
        $("#menu").css("margin-top","40px")
    });
});
```

Then, you need to change the css positioning of the `#menu` to `position: absolute`

**Edited:**

To make it animated, just add css transitions:

```
transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
```

Comment: Still no way to get the animated slide down huh?

Comment: ahh! so you want it to be animated ... just add css transition

Answer (score 0):

make the child nodes hidden at first.

```
#menuText {
     display:none;
     margin-top:360px;
     font-family:Verdana;
     font-size:30px;
     font-weight:bold;display:none;
}
```

then have this event handler..

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     $("#menu").click(function() {
          $("#menuText").slideDown(100);
     });
});
```